# Putting different elements in individual component/wheel of UIPickerView

Tags: iphone, ios, uipickerview

```
-(NSString *) pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    return [pickerArray objectAtIndex:row];
}
```

pickerArray is the name of the array having the elements which are going to be shown in the  UIPickerView.

If my Picker has 3 components, then the upper method fills everyone of them with he same array. How to fill it with different ones ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the `component` argument in the call is an integer value indicating que "wheel" that is filling, use something like this:

```
if (component == 0)
    return [pickerArray_0 objectAtIndex:row];
else if (component == 1)
    return [pickerArray_1 objectAtIndex:row];
else
    return [pickerArray_2 objectAtIndex:row];
```

Comment: still all three wheels will have same array values. I want diff. in each wheel at same time

Comment: Read the answer again. A different array is used for each component.